# print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):" pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

I was trying to run as ussually my library "pandas" but then I faced a mistake

```
import pandas as pd

DF_temp = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")
```

Output

```
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am working with python 3.7

I installed again xlrd but the same issue appears. How can I resolve this? Thank you

Comment: Based on the print statement lacking parenthesis, it looks like you are using a version of xlrd written for python 2.x. Try re-installing xlrd with a python 3 version.

Comment: python3 -m pip install --upgrade xlrd yes I tried with this command. But this was my result Could not fetch URL pypi.org/simple/pip: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused

Comment: Since this is an Anaconda install, it might be better to do `conda install xlrd`.

Comment: According to my experience, this problem occurs whenever I send the **excel** file via Telegram to my students. After downloading from Telegram, you probably need to open the excel file and **enable editing mode**. I do not understand why the file from Telegram is protected from running and editing.

Answer (score 21):

Had the same issue and used suggested fix
python3 -m pip install --upgrade xlrd
Worked for me even though I received some warning.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting xlrd
  Downloading xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 103 kB 6.0 MB/s eta 0:00:01
Installing collected packages: xlrd
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

camelot 12.6.29 requires SQLAlchemy<0.8.0,>=0.7.7, but you'll have sqlalchemy 1.3.14 which is incompatible.
camelot 12.6.29 requires xlrd==0.7.1, but you'll have xlrd 1.2.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed xlrd-1.2.0
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: Just an additional  Info: As we can see the logs showing in Hugo's answer, Module Camelot is the reason for XLRD to get downgrade sometime. Camelot needs XLRD version less than 2.0.1, but pandas need XLRD with version 2.0.1. 

So upgrade XLRD will fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The solution for the problem is updating the xlrd library. Just run this command and the problem will be solved:

```
!pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by downloading the updated pandas and xlrd packages.

1. open anaconda prompt
2. type `pip show xlrd` if the version is old then ,
3. `pip install xlrd==2.0.1` (the latest version)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we should upgrade our pip before installing any new package. You can follow this command :

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

After that, you can install xlrd package with the command:

```
pip install xlrd
```

Even after installing xlrd, you may face this same error again and again at that time please check proper extension of your excel file. Many time old version of excel throws error. It can be 'excel 5.0/95' file.

For this file you can install pyexcel or pyexcel_xls package to work ahead. You find the documentation of same in the [link](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xls)

use command:

```
pip install pyexcel
```

or

```
pip install pyexcel_xls
```

I'm not sure that this will work perfectly but, we can explore ahead to resolve such errors and issues.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to read 'Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet' type.

Try to open the workbook with xlrd package and then read it using the pandas read_excel function.

Below is code snippet

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file, logfile=open(devnull, 'w'))
df = df.append(pd.read_excel(wb, dtype=str, skiprows=1, engine='xlrd'), ignore_index=True)
```