# Why has pd.read_excel in jupyter stopped working and shows this error message?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a number of jupyter notebooks set up to read excel files. They were working fine until yesterday, when they started to deliver the error message shown. I've tried renaming xls files to xlsx and explicitly naming the engine as openpyxl, but nothing works. What's gone wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xls = pd.ExcelFile(('https://www5.cao.go.jp/keizai3/watcher-e/di.xls')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-aeef5030e4b9>", line 4, in <module>
    xls = pd.read_excel('https://www5.cao.go.jp/keizai3/watcher-e/di.xls')

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1043, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency(

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 106, in import_optional_dependency
    module = importlib.import_module(name)

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "/Users/paul/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If your file is one of the old-style .xls, you could try to add **engine='xlrd'** to the arguments of **pd.read_excel**

Comment: That looks like you've hit a Python 2 statement in one of the dependencies used to parse the old .xls file. From the docs, setting `engine="xlrd" supports old-style Excel files (.xls) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't think they are the reasons. The files were all working fine, and  now they are not. And, as I said, I have the same problems with xlsx files, with the problem starting at the pd.ExcelFile stage (I've edited the origina post to show that). The error messages are the same, ending in the line "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):".

Answer (score 0):

I think I've resolved it, after reading the response here. For me the conflict seems to have been with pdfminer. I uninstalled that, and the excel function is now working again, I think.

[print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):" pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63368983/print-externsheetb7-pandas)